# Pull data from a closed workbook to a userform using Vlookup

Tags: vba

In the following code, I copy a value from a closed-spreadsheet to a user-form, but it fails with `error 1004`.

> "Unable to get the Vlookup propoerty".

My code is as follows:

```
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
   MsgBox "Enter Employee Number", vbExclamation, "Error Message"

   Exit Sub

End If

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Z:\PROD  - Production related info\QUALITY\KAIZEN TEAM\Weekly Rejects\Dropdown_List_Database\Dropdown_Lists.xlsx")

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("Users").Range("A2:F1000")

UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = 
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value, myRange, 2, False)
```

Comment: What result do you get if you add `Debug.Print UserForm1.TextBox1.value,myRange` before the `Application.WorksheetFunction` line?

Comment: I'd suggest `Set myRange = wb.Worksheets("Users").Range("A2:F1000")`

Comment: If the answer helped you [please consider accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps others to find working answers.  If the answer didn't help add a comment.  Maybe it can be fixed.

Comment: i have used this method already and it result in same error

Answer (score 0):

[VLookup](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) will raise an error, when called via the [Application.WorksheetFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) object, if it cannot find the value you are looking for.  You can handle this by adding error trapping to your function:

**Test Data**

```
Row/Col     A   B
1           x   XXX
2           y   YYY
3           z   ZZZ
```

**Example A**

```
Public Sub XX()
On Error Resume Next    ' Ignore errors.  WARNING: Will ignore **all** errors.
Dim result As Variant   ' Holds result of vlookup.

    ' Can find value, no error.
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("x", Range("Sheet1!A1:B3"), 2, False)
    MsgBox result

    ' Cannot find value, raises an error.
    result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("a", Range("Sheet1!A1:B3"), 2, False)

    ' Check for error.
    ' 1004 = cannot find value.
    ' Make sure you handle all other errors.
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then

        MsgBox "Cannot find value"
        Err.Clear
    Else

        MsgBox Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

An alternative approach allows you to call VLookup directly.  This method does not require error trapping:

**Example B**

```
Dim Result As Variant

' Value XXX wrote to Result.
Result = [Vlookup("x", Sheet1!A1:B3, 2, False)]

' Value Error 2042 wrote to Result.
Result = [Vlookup("a", Sheet1!A1:B3, 2, False)]
```

I prefer the second approach.  Ignoring errors can make it hard to debug your code later.

For more on using VLookup via VBA I'd recommend reading this [blog post](http://www.microsofttraining.net/b/use-vlookup-function-excel-vba/).

Comment: my broblem really is not error handling, but it is as though my code is not or rather it is not working.  i have tried your option B, its given me the same error. i checked my data sheet and the data i want pulled to the userform is there.

Comment: If the value of `UserForm1.TextBox1` appears within `Users!A2:F1000` then it could be a data type error.  Vlookups won't match integers with strings, example: 1 <> "1".  What value are you looking up, when the code fails?